# What is the proper way to handle FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed with iOS FB SDK 3.1.1

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

When my app needs to e.g. read from a user's facebook, it checks the current state the active FBSession. For the e.g. `FBSessionStateOpen`, it knows it can just request the information from Facebook, whereas for `FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded` it must call `openWithCompletionHandler`. What `FBSession` method should be called if the current state is `FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed`?

Answer (score 1):

That means that a login attempt failed. When this happens for me I `- closeAndClearTokenInformation` and alert the user that login failed and ask him if he wants to login again.

Answer (score 0):

In short:
In Facebook sample
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/

When such condition occurred, their sample code will call a loginViewController or equivalent.

This is their comments when falling into this condition.
 "if the token goes invalid we want to switch right back to the login view, however we do it with a slight delay in order to account for a race between this and the login view dissappearing a moment before "

P.S. I fixed this error my solving Facebook open graph setups and study more on the Scrumptious example such as "return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];" and "[FBSession.activeSession handleDidBecomeActive];"

In long:
This is taken from official FB doc.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.1/class/FBSession#FBSessionState+enum

Given this is the precondition and it has passed other enum states and not a connection error:
"FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed
Closed session state indicating that a login attempt failed"

It didn't explicitly said the problem. It may be the cached misinformation. Personally and most carefully, I would call '- (void)closeAndClearTokenInformation;", this method would clean up every cache info and show a error message such as "invalid login, please try again" to the client/user.

Then, allow the client the options to do a clean slate login again or skip this process if possible.

HTH